# Upgrade to Vim 7.4 in OS X El Capitan

Tags: vim, osx-elcapitan

I am new to Vim but am determined to learn it. I am on OS X El Capitan and have tried upgrading Vim 7.3 to 7.4 using several options but with no success.

I have used `brew install with --with-system-override-vim` option but although I can see that vim 7.4 is installed when I start my Vim editor it again reverts back to 7.3 version only.

Can anyone please guide me through the process of making sure that the system version is upgraded to 7.4.

Comment: Is homebrew installing vim in a different location? What's the output of `which vim`?

Comment: when i type the command which vim the output is -->  /usr/bin/vim but which i do vim --version it is still VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 22 2015 15:38:58)
Compiled by root@apple.com

Comment: Ok, and how are you "seeing that vim 7.4 is installed"?

Comment: brew install vim --with-system-override-vim
==> Downloading https://github.com/vim/vim/archive/v7.4.891.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/vim-7.4.891.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.891/share/man --enable-
==> make
==> make install prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.891 STRIP=true
  /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.891: 1612 files, 29M, built in 34 seconds

Comment: And what's the output of `ls /usr/bin | grep vim`?

Comment: rvim
vim
vimdiff
vimtutor

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure homebrew installs vim under `/usr/local/bin/`

You really shouldn't overwrite the system vim, you should an alias to your `.bash_profile` file,

```
alias vim='/usr/local/bin/vim'
```

The other option would be to "hide" the current vim

```
mv /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim73
```

And then when you run the `vim` command it won't find it under `/usr/bin/` and will look in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: i am using zsh shell so should i insert the command you suggested in .zshrc .

Comment: I've never personally used `zsh`, but that sounds right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with inserting the line alias vim in the .zshrc worked

Answer (score 0):

@dursk answer is correct, but I didn't have "/usr/local/bin/vim". My solution was to upgrade to latest version of MacVim it's 8.0 now ( http://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/) install MacVim via .dmg file

after adding line below to `.bash_profile` file in user root folder

`alias vim="/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"`

After should run command `source ~/.bash_profile` to update bash_profile settings

Answer (score 0):

Don't replace the system `vi`/`vim` in `/usr/bin`. Instead, use `homebrew` to install a newer version of `vim`:

```
brew update
brew install vim
```

That will install a newer `vim` to `/usr/local/bin/vim`. Make sure that your `$PATH` has `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`. You would probably also want to add a symlink for `vi` in `/usr/local/bin` as well:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/vim /usr/local/bin/vi

which vim # verify that it is /usr/local/bin/vim
which vi # verify that it is /usr/local/bin/vi
```